# Large script with many parts... how can I optimize this?

Tags: php

I have a script that is taking in information from one table, determining if it needs to make an entry for another table (avoiding duplicates) and then inserting the information into the pages table.  The problem is, doing queries for approx 10,000 entries the way it's currently coded, is making causing performance issues.

What way could I optimize this in order to make it run more efficiently and quicker? As you can see from the code, there are many parts to this.

```
$eventquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM maintable WHERE PCatID != '3' AND PCatID != '4'");
while($event = mysql_fetch_array($eventquery))
{
$querystring = null;
$performer_id = array();
$hasharray = array();
$venue = preg_replace("/ \([fF]ormerly (.+?)\)/", '', $event['Venue']);

$perfquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM maintable WHERE EventID = '".$event['EventID']."'");   
while($perf = mysql_fetch_array($perfquery))
    {
        $performer_id[$perf['PerformerID']] = $perf['Performer'];
        $hasharray[] = $perf['id'];
    }

$eventtime = getEventTime($event['DateTime']);
$performer_id = serialize($performer_id);
$hasharray = serialize($hasharray);

if($event['PCatID'] == "2" && $event['CCatID'] != "24")
{
    $request = "buy-".strCleanupForPage($event['Event'])."-concert-tickets/".strCleanupForPage($event['City'])."-".
        strCleanupForPage(stateabb($event['State']))."-".strCleanupForPage($venue)."-".$eventtime['date'];

    $catnum = "202";

    $querystring = "INSERT IGNORE INTO pages (request, catnum, name, perfarray, event_id, hasharray, mainpage) VALUES 
        ('".$request."','".$catnum."','".addslashes($event['Event'])."','".addslashes($performer_id)."',
            '".$event['EventID']."','".$hasharray."','n')";


}
elseif($event['GCatID'] == "32" || $event['GCatID'] == "16" || $event['GCatID'] == "30" || $event['GCatID'] == "19" ||
         $event['GCatID'] == "31" || $event['GCatID'] == "22")
{ 
    if($event['GCatID'] == "32")
        {$catnum = "102";}
    elseif($event['GCatID'] == "16")
        {$catnum = "101";}
    elseif($event['GCatID'] == "30")
        {$catnum = "103";}
    elseif($event['GCatID'] == "19")
        {$catnum = "104";}
    elseif($event['GCatID'] == "31")
        {$catnum = "109";}
    elseif($event['GCatID'] == "22")
        {$catnum = "108";}
    elseif($event['GCatID'] == "17")
        {
            if($event['CCatID'] == "66")
                {$catnum = "106";}
            elseif($event['CCatID'] == "65")
                {$catnum = "105";}
        }

    if(strstr($event['Event']," vs. "))
        {
            $game = true;
            $teams = explode(" vs. ",$event['Event']);
        }
    elseif(strstr($event['Event']," Vs. "))
        {
            $game = true;
            $teams = explode(" Vs. ",$event['Event']);
        }
    else
        {
            $game = false;            
        }

    if($game)
        {           

            $catnum .= "2";
            $homequery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sportsteams WHERE fullname LIKE '".$teams[0]."'");  
            $home = mysql_fetch_array($homequery);  
            $awayquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sportsteams WHERE fullname LIKE '".$teams[1]."'");  
            $away = mysql_fetch_array($awayquery);

            if((mysql_num_rows($homequery)) == 0 || (mysql_num_rows($awayquery)) == 0)
            {
                if($catnum == "1012")
                    {$request = "mlb-baseball-tickets";}
                elseif($catnum == "1022")
                    {$request = "nfl-football-tickets";}
                elseif($catnum == "1032")
                    {$request = "nba-basketball-tickets";}
                elseif($catnum == "1042")
                    {$request = "nhl-hockey-tickets";}
                elseif($catnum == "1052")
                    {$request = "ncaa-football-tickets";}
                elseif($catnum == "1062")
                    {$request = "ncaa-basketball-tickets";}
                elseif($catnum == "1082")
                    {$request = "mls-soccer-tickets";}
                elseif($catnum == "1092")
                    {$request = "wnba-basketball-tickets";}
                $eventname = preg_replace("/\([iI]ncludes (.+?)\)/", '', $event['Event']);
                $request .= "/".strCleanupForPage($eventname)."-".strCleanupForPage($event['City'])."-".
                     strCleanupForPage(stateabb($event['State']));
                }
            else
                {
                    $request = strCleanupForPage($home['fullname'])."-tickets-".strCleanupForPage($venue)."/".strCleanupForPage($home['nickname'])."-vs-".strCleanupForPage($away['nickname'])."-".strCleanupForPage($event['City'])."-".
                    strCleanupForPage(stateabb($event['State']))."-".$eventtime['date'];
                    $request = str_replace("-/","/",$request);
                }

        $querystring = "INSERT IGNORE INTO pages (request, catnum, name, perfarray, event_id, hasharray, mainpage) VALUES 
        ('".$request."','".$catnum."','".addslashes($event['Event'])."','".addslashes($performer_id)."',
            '".$event['EventID']."','".$hasharray."','n')";
    }
    else
    {   
        $catnum .= "3";
        if($catnum == "1013")
            {$request = "mlb-baseball";}
        elseif($catnum == "1023")
            {$request = "nfl-football";}
        elseif($catnum == "1033")
            {$request = "nba-basketball";}
        elseif($catnum == "1043")
            {$request = "nhl-hockey";}
        elseif($catnum == "1053")
            {$request = "ncaa-football";}
        elseif($catnum == "1063")
            {$request = "ncaa-basketball";}
        elseif($catnum == "1083")
            {$request = "mls-soccer";}
        elseif($catnum == "1093")
            {$request = "wnba-basketball";}

        $eventname = preg_replace("/\([iI]ncludes (.+?)\)/", '', $event['Event']);
        $request .= "/".strCleanupForPage($eventname)."-".strCleanupForPage($event['City'])."-".
        strCleanupForPage(stateabb($event['State']));

        $querystring = "INSERT IGNORE INTO pages (request, catnum, name, perfarray, event_id, hasharray, mainpage) VALUES 
        ('".$request."','".$catnum."','".addslashes($event['Event'])."','".addslashes($performer_id)."',
            '".$event['EventID']."','".$hasharray."','n')";
    }
}
elseif($event['CCatID'] == "50")
{
    $request = "boxing-tickets/".strCleanupForPage($event['Event'])."-".strCleanupForPage($event['City'])."-".$eventtime['date'];
    $querystring = "INSERT IGNORE INTO pages (request, catnum, name, perfarray, event_id, hasharray) VALUES
        ('".$request."','1142','".addslashes($event['Event'])."','".addslashes($performer_id)."','".$event['EventID']."',
            '".$hasharray."')";
}    
elseif($event['CCatID'] == "67")
{
    $request = "golf-tickets/".strCleanupForPage($event['Event'])."-".strCleanupForPage($event['City'])."-".$eventtime['date'];
    $querystring = "INSERT IGNORE INTO pages (request, catnum, name, perfarray, event_id, hasharray) VALUES
        ('".$request."','1112','".addslashes($event['Event'])."','".addslashes($performer_id)."','".$event['EventID']."',
            '".$hasharray."')";
}    
elseif($event['CCatID'] == "27")
{
    $request = "tennis-tickets/".strCleanupForPage($event['Event'])."-".strCleanupForPage($event['City'])."-".$eventtime['date'];
    $querystring = "INSERT IGNORE INTO pages (request, catnum, name, perfarray, event_id, hasharray) VALUES
        ('".$request."','1102','".addslashes($event['Event'])."','".addslashes($performer_id)."','".$event['EventID']."',
            '".$hasharray."')";
}    
elseif($event['CCatID'] == "101")
{
    $request = "ufc-mma-tickets/".strCleanupForPage($event['Event'])."-".strCleanupForPage($event['City'])."-".$eventtime['date'];
    $querystring = "INSERT IGNORE INTO pages (request, catnum, name, perfarray, event_id, hasharray) VALUES
        ('".$request."','1152','".addslashes($event['Event'])."','".addslashes($performer_id)."','".$event['EventID']."',
            '".$hasharray."')";
}    
elseif($event['CCatID'] == "69")
{
    if(strstr($event['Event'],"NASCAR"))
    {                    
        $request = "nascar-tickets/".strCleanupForPage($event['Event'])."-".strCleanupForPage($event['City'])."-".$eventtime['date'];
        $querystring = "INSERT IGNORE INTO pages (request, catnum, name, perfarray, event_id, hasharray) VALUES
            ('".$request."','1122','".addslashes($event['Event'])."','".addslashes($performer_id)."','".$event['EventID']."',
            '".$hasharray."')";
    }
    elseif($event['GCatID'] == "35")
    {
        $request = "horse-racing-tickets/".strCleanupForPage($event['Event'])."-".strCleanupForPage($event['City'])."-".$eventtime['date'];
        $querystring = "INSERT IGNORE INTO pages (request, catnum, name, perfarray, event_id, hasharray) VALUES
            ('".$request."','1132','".addslashes($event['Event'])."','".addslashes($performer_id)."','".$event['EventID']."',
            '".$hasharray."')";
    }
}
elseif($event['GCatID'] == "26")
{
    $request = "wwe-tickets/".strCleanupForPage($event['Event'])."-".strCleanupForPage($event['City'])."-".$eventtime['date'];
    $querystring = "INSERT IGNORE INTO pages (request, catnum, name, perfarray, event_id, hasharray) VALUES
        ('".$request."','1162','".addslashes($event['Event'])."','".addslashes($performer_id)."','".$event['EventID']."',
            '".$hasharray."')";
}
elseif($event['CCatID'] == "24")
{   
    $catnum = "402";
    $request = strCleanupForPage($event['Event'])."-comedy-tickets/".strCleanupForPage($event['City'])."-".strCleanupForPage(stateabb($event['State'])).
        "-".strCleanupForPage($event['Venue'])."-".$eventtime['date'];
    $querystring = "INSERT IGNORE INTO pages (request, catnum, name, perfarray, event_id, hasharray, mainpage) VALUES 
        ('".$request."','".$catnum."','".addslashes($event['Event'])."','".addslashes($performer_id)."',
            '".$event['EventID']."','".$hasharray."','n')";
}

if($querystring)
{
    $request = str_replace("--","-",$request);
    if(!mysql_query($querystring))
        {
            exit("<br>" . mysql_error());
        }
    else
    {
        if(mysql_affected_rows() != 0)
            {               
                echo date('H:i:s') . ": ";
                echo $request . " entry inserted<br>";
            }
        else
            {
                //echo "<i>" .$request . " entry ignored</i><br>";
            }
    }
}

}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: Or could you please point out anything that I could change to help the performance of this script??

Comment: first of all you should start using PDO next.. make your code more readable ... break into smaller function .... tooooo much nesting... replace if elseif with switch ...  try to optimize query...

Comment: to be honest i can not go through your code not even read ... its not readable... add comments on your code that will help u in the future...

Comment: Okay, thanks for the advice... I am still a bit new to programming with php.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for opportunities to refactor, here are some common code-scents that give away an area that could be improved:

The long if / elseif/ else statement:

```
if () {
    ...
} elseif () {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

Some people like to replace them with a `switch` statement, but object orientation has more powerful tools for dealing with this. Sometimes, just a well written method could reduce the need for them.

Another thing I notice in your code are duplicate actions on (seemingly) different conditions:

```
if(strstr($event['Event']," vs. "))
    {
        $game = true;
        $teams = explode(" vs. ",$event['Event']);
    }
elseif(strstr($event['Event']," Vs. "))
    {
        $game = true;
        $teams = explode(" Vs. ",$event['Event']);
    }
```

If you did a case-insensitive comparison, you would save five lines of nearly identical code

```
if(stristr ($event['Event']," vs. "))
{
    $game = true;
    $teams = explode(" vs. ",$event['Event']);
}
```

You can reduce nesting and aid readability by inverting an if statement within a function:

```
if($querystring)
{
    // lots of code here
    // lots of code here
    // lots of code here
    // lots of code here
}
```

Becomes

```
if(!$querystring)
{
    return;
}

// lots of code here
// lots of code here
// lots of code here
// lots of code here
```

This is especially useful when you have nested if statements as the more nesting you have, the harder it is to read.

In terms of performance, the more times you take a trip to the database, the slower your code will be. If you can batch up queries, or avoid them altogether - that is the part of your code that is costing you the most in terms of milliseconds used!

Note on performance: You should optimize your code for readability in the first instance. Make it easy to read and easy to change. Then measure it. If it takes too long, then look at performance tuning. Measure after each change to see if it really improves performance.

Comment: That is very helpful.  I am currently creating a backup of the script to do some testing and I will take this all into account.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to change this:

```
        $catnum .= "3";
    if($catnum == "1013")
        {$request = "mlb-baseball";}
    elseif($catnum == "1023")
        {$request = "nfl-football";}
    elseif($catnum == "1033")
        {$request = "nba-basketball";}
    elseif($catnum == "1043")
        {$request = "nhl-hockey";}
    elseif($catnum == "1053")
        {$request = "ncaa-football";}
    elseif($catnum == "1063")
        {$request = "ncaa-basketball";}
    elseif($catnum == "1083")
        {$request = "mls-soccer";}
    elseif($catnum == "1093")
        {$request = "wnba-basketball";}
```

And rewrite it with the switch [`switch`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)

Comment: Thanks... would that make a difference in execution time?

Comment: dont even need switch store in assoc array then pass key to get value.. three line and done

Comment: Or better yet, move it far far away from the main logic (say, into a database perhaps!?).

Comment: i have just made an solution that would reduce code because if else with many options is not the right approach but as the above commenters wrote here there are other options too

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT1**: I updated the code below to avoid SQL injection (and it makes it shorter and easier to read).

The biggest performance increase will be to insert multiple records at once, via `INSERT INTO ... (fields) VALUES (values1),(values2)...`. Here's an example:

```
$eventquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM maintable WHERE PCatID != '3' AND PCatID != '4'");
$page_fields = array();
while($event = mysql_fetch_array($eventquery))
{
    $querystring = null;
    $performer_id = array();
    $hasharray = array();
    $venue = preg_replace("/ \(formerly (.+?)\)/i", '', $event['Venue']);

    $perfquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM maintable WHERE EventID = '".$event['EventID']."'");   
    while($perf = mysql_fetch_array($perfquery))
        {
            $performer_id[$perf['PerformerID']] = $perf['Performer'];
            $hasharray[] = $perf['id'];
        }

    $eventtime = getEventTime($event['DateTime']);
    $performer_id = serialize($performer_id);
    $hasharray = serialize($hasharray);

    if($event['PCatID'] == "2" && $event['CCatID'] != "24")
    {
        $request = "buy-".strCleanupForPage($event['Event'])."-concert-tickets/".strCleanupForPage($event['City'])."-".
            strCleanupForPage(stateabb($event['State']))."-".strCleanupForPage($venue)."-".$eventtime['date'];

        $catnum = "202";

        $page_fields[] = array($request, $catnum, $event['Event'], $performer_id, $event['EventID'], $hasharray, 'n');
    }
    elseif($event['GCatID'] == "32" || $event['GCatID'] == "16" || $event['GCatID'] == "30" || $event['GCatID'] == "19" ||
             $event['GCatID'] == "31" || $event['GCatID'] == "22")
    { 
        if($event['GCatID'] == "32")
            {$catnum = "102";}
        elseif($event['GCatID'] == "16")
            {$catnum = "101";}
        elseif($event['GCatID'] == "30")
            {$catnum = "103";}
        elseif($event['GCatID'] == "19")
            {$catnum = "104";}
        elseif($event['GCatID'] == "31")
            {$catnum = "109";}
        elseif($event['GCatID'] == "22")
            {$catnum = "108";}
        elseif($event['GCatID'] == "17")
            {
                if($event['CCatID'] == "66")
                    {$catnum = "106";}
                elseif($event['CCatID'] == "65")
                    {$catnum = "105";}
            }

        if(strstr($event['Event']," vs. "))
            {
                $game = true;
                $teams = explode(" vs. ",$event['Event']);
            }
        elseif(strstr($event['Event']," Vs. "))
            {
                $game = true;
                $teams = explode(" Vs. ",$event['Event']);
            }
        else
            {
                $game = false;            
            }

        if($game)
            {           

                $catnum .= "2";
                $homequery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sportsteams WHERE fullname LIKE '".$teams[0]."'");  
                $home = mysql_fetch_array($homequery);  
                $awayquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sportsteams WHERE fullname LIKE '".$teams[1]."'");  
                $away = mysql_fetch_array($awayquery);

                if((mysql_num_rows($homequery)) == 0 || (mysql_num_rows($awayquery)) == 0)
                {
                    if($catnum == "1012")
                        {$request = "mlb-baseball-tickets";}
                    elseif($catnum == "1022")
                        {$request = "nfl-football-tickets";}
                    elseif($catnum == "1032")
                        {$request = "nba-basketball-tickets";}
                    elseif($catnum == "1042")
                        {$request = "nhl-hockey-tickets";}
                    elseif($catnum == "1052")
                        {$request = "ncaa-football-tickets";}
                    elseif($catnum == "1062")
                        {$request = "ncaa-basketball-tickets";}
                    elseif($catnum == "1082")
                        {$request = "mls-soccer-tickets";}
                    elseif($catnum == "1092")
                        {$request = "wnba-basketball-tickets";}
                    $eventname = preg_replace("/\([iI]ncludes (.+?)\)/", '', $event['Event']);
                    $request .= "/".strCleanupForPage($eventname)."-".strCleanupForPage($event['City'])."-".
                         strCleanupForPage(stateabb($event['State']));
                    }
                else
                    {
                        $request = strCleanupForPage($home['fullname'])."-tickets-".strCleanupForPage($venue)."/".strCleanupForPage($home['nickname'])."-vs-".strCleanupForPage($away['nickname'])."-".strCleanupForPage($event['City'])."-".
                        strCleanupForPage(stateabb($event['State']))."-".$eventtime['date'];
                        $request = str_replace("-/","/",$request);
                    }

            $page_fields[] = array($request, $catnum, $event['Event'], $performer_id, $event['EventID'], $hasharray, 'n');
        }
        else
        {   
            $catnum .= "3";
            if($catnum == "1013")
                {$request = "mlb-baseball";}
            elseif($catnum == "1023")
                {$request = "nfl-football";}
            elseif($catnum == "1033")
                {$request = "nba-basketball";}
            elseif($catnum == "1043")
                {$request = "nhl-hockey";}
            elseif($catnum == "1053")
                {$request = "ncaa-football";}
            elseif($catnum == "1063")
                {$request = "ncaa-basketball";}
            elseif($catnum == "1083")
                {$request = "mls-soccer";}
            elseif($catnum == "1093")
                {$request = "wnba-basketball";}

            $eventname = preg_replace("/\([iI]ncludes (.+?)\)/", '', $event['Event']);
            $request .= "/".strCleanupForPage($eventname)."-".strCleanupForPage($event['City'])."-".
            strCleanupForPage(stateabb($event['State']));

            $page_fields[] = array($request, $catnum, $event['Event'], $performer_id, $event['EventID'], $hasharray, 'n');
        }
    }
    elseif($event['CCatID'] == "50")
    {
        $request = "boxing-tickets/".strCleanupForPage($event['Event'])."-".strCleanupForPage($event['City'])."-".$eventtime['date'];
        $catnum = '1142';
        $page_fields[] = array($request, $catnum, $event['Event'], $performer_id, $event['EventID'], $hasharray, 'n');
    }    
    elseif($event['CCatID'] == "67")
    {
        $request = "golf-tickets/".strCleanupForPage($event['Event'])."-".strCleanupForPage($event['City'])."-".$eventtime['date'];
        $catnum = '1112';
        $page_fields[] = array($request, $catnum, $event['Event'], $performer_id, $event['EventID'], $hasharray, 'n');
    }    
    elseif($event['CCatID'] == "27")
    {
        $request = "tennis-tickets/".strCleanupForPage($event['Event'])."-".strCleanupForPage($event['City'])."-".$eventtime['date'];
        $catnum = '1102';
        $page_fields[] = array($request, $catnum, $event['Event'], $performer_id, $event['EventID'], $hasharray, 'n');
    }    
    elseif($event['CCatID'] == "101")
    {
        $request = "ufc-mma-tickets/".strCleanupForPage($event['Event'])."-".strCleanupForPage($event['City'])."-".$eventtime['date'];
        $catnum = '1152';
        $page_fields[] = array($request, $catnum, $event['Event'], $performer_id, $event['EventID'], $hasharray, 'n');
    }    
    elseif($event['CCatID'] == "69")
    {
        if(strstr($event['Event'],"NASCAR"))
        {                    
            $request = "nascar-tickets/".strCleanupForPage($event['Event'])."-".strCleanupForPage($event['City'])."-".$eventtime['date'];
            $catnum = '1122';
            $page_fields[] = array($request, $catnum, $event['Event'], $performer_id, $event['EventID'], $hasharray, 'n');
        }
        elseif($event['GCatID'] == "35")
        {
            $request = "horse-racing-tickets/".strCleanupForPage($event['Event'])."-".strCleanupForPage($event['City'])."-".$eventtime['date'];
            $catnum = '1132';
            $page_fields[] = array($request, $catnum, $event['Event'], $performer_id, $event['EventID'], $hasharray, 'n');
        }
    }
    elseif($event['GCatID'] == "26")
    {
        $request = "wwe-tickets/".strCleanupForPage($event['Event'])."-".strCleanupForPage($event['City'])."-".$eventtime['date'];
        $catnum = '1162';
        $page_fields[] = array($request, $catnum, $event['Event'], $performer_id, $event['EventID'], $hasharray, 'n');
    }
    elseif($event['CCatID'] == "24")
    {   
        $catnum = "402";
        $request = strCleanupForPage($event['Event'])."-comedy-tickets/".strCleanupForPage($event['City'])."-".strCleanupForPage(stateabb($event['State'])).
            "-".strCleanupForPage($event['Venue'])."-".$eventtime['date'];
        $page_fields[] = array($request, $catnum, $event['Event'], $performer_id, $event['EventID'], $hasharray, 'n');
    }

    if($page_fields)
    {
        $rows = array();
        foreach ($page_fields as $fields) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($fields), ++$i) {
                $fields[$i] = sprintf("'%s'", mysql_escape_string($fields[$i]));
            }
            $rows[] = sprintf('(%s)', join(',', $fields));
        }
        $querystring = "INSERT IGNORE INTO pages (request, catnum, name, perfarray, event_id, hasharray, mainpage) VALUES\n"
            . join(",\n", $rows);

        $request = str_replace("--","-",$request);
        if(!mysql_query($querystring))
            {
                exit("<br>" . mysql_error());
            }
        else
        {
            if(mysql_affected_rows() != 0)
                {               
                    echo date('H:i:s') . ": ";
                    echo $request . " entry inserted<br>";
                }
            else
                {
                    //echo "<i>" .$request . " entry ignored</i><br>";
                }
        }
    }

}
```

Of course, you may to tweak the `max_allowed_packet` and/or `bulk_insert_buffer_size` settings, if you hit the limits set on your system.

Comment: I like that idea!  I will absolutely be trying to see how much of an impact it would make. Thank you!

Comment: Would it make more sense to check to see if the row exists before trying to insert/ignore it?

Comment: Perhaps, if a good portion of you INSERTs were ignored. But for performance, do a single SELECT, and load the results in an array and check against that.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't that long? And if you want to reduce complexity of code, in large apps, switch to object oriented programming. 
You are still using deprecated functions like mysql_query. It's support hasn't been removed, but its use is discouraged. Switch to a more object oriented approach. PDO is best

Comment: It may not be long code wise but the length and resources used to run the script is very noticeable.

Comment: stop using mysql_query, use mysqli_query or PDO.

Answer (score 0):

Your database structure seems terribly strange, however I could be wrong as your code is rather horrible to read.

One problem is that it's not normalized. For the `maintable` you have to do several selects for 1 event. Well, your main table should firstly change name and then hold only events and the data directly related to only the event.

For performers or teams participating you want to query another table (probably with a join for this script) which holds the event id together with the performers data.

Your category IDs should also be in the database and can also be joined in the first query. Any category properties that makes handling different you would also store in this table.

Your problem is not that you have 10k rows, it is the database structure.

Read up on database normalization and especially third normal form. Then give it a good try and feel free to come back and ask about the result.

Comment: There's no argument as far as code and database structure... this is not my code, I am now responsible for it however.  This was coded by someone else that didn't take into account the amount of rows that would soon be in this database.

Comment: Well, looking at the way queries have to go through the flow - it seems that the only improvement which will make bulk part of performance benefit is restructuring the database. And if it's a full and extensive application there already ... the only decent chance to restructure the database is to first structure up the code in a good OOP fashion.